# Why debris from previous questions in question input box?

Tags: support

When I am entering a question (in main), it often happens that debris, apparently from some previous question, shows up (in a kind of background typeface). Surely others have experienced this bug as well. Any hope for a quick fix?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "debris." Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: I am guessing it is the saved draft from an unposted question of yours.

Comment: It is a [feature, not a bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1177/allow-questions-to-be-saved-as-drafts-prior-to-posting/66238#66238).

Answer (score 6):

As Willie pointed out, this is an automatic drafts feature.

[Allow questions to be saved as drafts prior to posting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1177/allow-questions-to-be-saved-as-drafts-prior-to-posting/66238#66238)

In addition to what was said there, we support only one draft per question or answer per site. It is also cleared every time you successfully post a question or answer, respectively.